# Globally disabling finding Non-code usages in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently upgraded to `Intellij IDEA 13.1.2` and the **Find Usages** command has started including Non-code usages which is very annoying/slow when searching for common words.  I realize you can open up the **Find Usages Settings** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>) to disable this, but it's only on a per-search basis.  I want to disable it for all searches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ability to "permanently" set find usage options was changed. The "Find Usage Settings" now resets each time. :( I recommend you vote for and comment on these issue reports:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120751
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124711

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a global setting, but will help address the slowness:  in the "Project" panel, identify directories in your project that contain large non-code files, right-click select "Mark Directory as>Excluded" from the menu.

Myself my project directory contained a 'log' directory, plus other directories containing many generated files, and a reports directory containing Junit and checkstyle reports etc. After marking these all as excluded, the Find Usages function was much faster yay.